# OFXbox2d - how to change joint type?

Tags: box2d, openframeworks

beginner question - I'm working with ofxBox2d (openframeworks) and can't figure out how to change the joint to another type (gear joint, revolute joint). It seems to default to distance joint .... any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should post your answer as an actual answer instead of a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question :) You need to augment ofxBox2d (which is quite wonderful), like Nay did in this post, for the RevoluteJoint: forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,3411.0.html